# Very slow mongo query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got a modell like this in node.js / moongose app for my matches.

```
var MatchSchema   = new Schema({
    race:       { type: Number, required: true},
    type:       { type: Number, required: true},
    path:       { type: Number, required: true},
    track:      { type: Number, required: true},
    players:    [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player', required: true }],
    scores:     [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Score',  required: true }],
});
```

And a modell for scores

```
var ScoreSchema   = new Schema({
    player:      { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player', required: true },
    match:       { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match',  required: true },
    score:       { type: Number, required: true},
});
```

And I want to query the database for the highest scores for a particular track, path, type and player. The players field is a array of ObjectId of players. I do it know like this:

```
// Find all matches of the right type, track, path for the player
Match.find( { path: path, track: track, players: {$in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(player)]}, type: type }, function(err, matches) {
    if(err || !matches) {
        // error handler...
    } else {
        var ids = matches.map(function(match) {
            return match._id;
        });
        // Find the scores from the matches and sort on score
        Score.aggregate([
            // match
            {
                "$match": { match: {$in: ids}}
            },
            // sort
            {
                "$sort": { score: -1 }
            },
            // skip
            {
                "$skip": skip
            },
            // limit
            {
                "$limit": limit
            }
        ], function(err, scores) {
            if (err || !scores) {
                // error handler
            } else {
                // do something cool
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But it is extremly slow, it takes about for 3 seconds to find the Matches and 1 second to get/and sort the scores. I got in total 6000 matches i my database and get 1000 documents from the Matches.find() - function. How can I redesign my querys and/or my modells to get better perfomrance.

Comment: Can you give us an explain output of the query?

Comment: Do you have indexes (like on `match` field)? How big `Score` collection is?

Comment: @freakish The first query is the slowest, about 3s. No I dont have indexes.

Comment: @Goran Indexes will surely improve the performance. However 3 secs on such small collection is waaay to much even for sequential scan. It is possible that this is actually related to DB configuration. Does it run on the same host? Or maybe you run out of resources like memory or network or you have too high iops?

Comment: @Sammaye What do you mean? Sample output or what Im trying to do? Im trying to build a higscore list for a user that have played matches with type, path, track. Type is the type of the track, 0 for example is offroad. Path is the path of the track (a track can have severals paths to race) and track is the track raced.

Comment: @freakish For now the database is hosted on MongoLabs and the web app is on heroku.

Comment: MongoDB can a function you can run within the cursor called `explain()` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/ it works the same as SQLs in telling us why your query is slow, but yes you don't have indexes, that could explain it, however, 3 secs is a long time for 6k docs

Comment: db.matches.find( { path: 0, track: 0, type: 0, players: {$in: [ObjectId("53abefaa7471c83c0d8ea76a")]}  } ).explain();
 gives millis: between 4-7 and
var ids = m.map(function(ma) {
 return ma._id;
});
db.scores.find( { match: {$in: ids}}  ).explain(); gives millis: between 4-8. Is the millis: field the number of milli seconds it took to complete the query?

Comment: Can you edit the question with the full output?